# Lockerbie bombing - amount of debris (confusing numbers)

Tags: accident-investigation

As mentioned on [Pan Am Flight 103](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_Am_Flight_103#Investigation):

> ... In total 4 million pieces of wreckage were collected and registered on
>   computer files. More than 10,000 pieces of debris were retrieved,
>   tagged and entered into a computer tracking system.

This is a bit confusing, at least to me. So which one is the actual number? Or if both sentences are correct, what is the difference between them?

Comment: IMO most likely explanation is 2 edits from different times with different sources

Comment: Any idea which one is correct number? Tried to look thru official report but I can't seem to find the number in there. 10k seems low - perhaps this number describes some pieces that had a specific meaning for the investigation? Or specific type?

Comment: I believe both numbers are correct. There were millions of pieces of wreckage from the plane as well as the surrounding houses that were destroyed. Everything was collected and examined. Of those ~4 mil pieces of wreckage, something over 10000 pieces of debris were confirmed to be from the plane.

Comment: This actually makes sense CGCampbell, thanks. In other words then, investigators were able to identify 10k as plane parts but it doesn't mean these were all of them?

Answer (score -2):

Pieces of wreckage implies a large 'section' of plane, whereas debris suggests miscellaneous smaller items and bits of metal etc.

I agree it's potentially confusing, however, and likely arises from two people editing the same section without adjusting the context.

I'd say that 4 substantial sections of plane were found, along with a large amount of smaller debris scattered around, totalling around 10,000 pieces.

Comment: They must have been feeding from two different sources then. I mean, the 4 million pieces is published on natgeo website (http://www.natgeotv.com/za/air-crash-investigation/lockerbie). But the Lockerbie Bombing wiki page (as opposed to pan am flight 103 wiki page) says 10,000 items. I'm surprised the number is not stated in the raport

Comment: @belinea, there are potentially dozens of ways to count debris... The question was about the specific sentence on Wikipedia.

Comment: I think you might have missed the "million" in the original quote

Comment: @JonStory Wikipedia said 4 million pieces of wreckage and 10,000 of debris, and you said wreckage are large pieces and debris is small. So they found 4 million large pieces and 10,000 small ones?